# how to build an application with light-4j that supports both Rest and GraphQL

Tags: rest, graphql, microservices, light-4j

I am building a new Rest service with several endpoints and also want to support GraphQL endpoint in the same instance, it is possible to do that with Light-4j?

Answer (score 0):

In the handler.yml, you can define two chains of middleware handlers. One for REST endpoints and one for GraphQL endpoints.

Here is one example that has two chains defined.

https://github.com/networknt/light-config-test/blob/master/light-router/local-portal/config/handler.yml

In fact, for all the GraphQL example, there are two Rest endpoints generated from the light-codegen for server info and health check.

Take a look at this example and you can add more Rest endpoints.

https://github.com/networknt/light-example-4j/blob/release/graphql/mutation-idl/src/main/resources/config/handler.yml